# Associate metadata account to token

Tags: node.js, token, metadata, solana

I have token X in solana with a token address and an associated token account.
I want to add a metadata account to that token X, meaning token X will have metadata pointing to an off-chain (external) json file .
I only familiar with cli and I didn't find any other tool enabling this request.

How can I create this metadata account and associate it to the token ?

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the official way, but if you want to create metadata for your token using the Metaplex standard, they have a CLI that you can use for it: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/tree/master/token-metadata/cli

You can check out and try running:

```
$ cargo run -- create_metadata_accounts --name TokenName --symbol SYMB --mint your_token_mint_here --uri https://uri.to.point.to --mutable
```

Source code can be found at: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/ed7c5c0202088fd60e43a532a2a73cb98eea5c58/token-metadata/cli/src/main.rs#L648